# knightlab timeline js - how to show events without overlap each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeline.js

Developing Timeline for Medical filed(Practicitioner) using Knightlab timelinejs. In that knightlabjs - How to show events without overlap each other with tags. let I tell example that 2012 jan 1st have 4 events. these four events have the same tag name called Mediator.How can show these four events without overlap eachother in same tag?

Please help me out
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try giving them different times for that day, for example the event you want to show 1st, is setted to 2012 jan 1st 08:00, the second at 2012 jan 1st 09:00 etc...in this way I think you can customize the order.
You can also set milliseconds.